# Insert array data using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using form to insert data into SQL.

This is my form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
    Name:<input type="text" name="firstname[]" />
</form>
```

and this is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
while ($array = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO test(firstname) VALUES ('{$array['firstname']}')";
    $result = $database->query($query);
}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

It shows an error. Any help?

Comment: Wow.  Lots of confusion there.  Perhaps start with the error message you receive, and work your way back from there.  Or follow a tutorial.  Perhaps consider first how `$result` is defined before one enters your `while` loop...

Comment: Please don't build yet another web app using w3schools techniques. It's ten years out of date. Try a framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/) to take care of routine stuff like this for you. It's not even hard. If you're just getting started you're going to make too many mistakes trying to go it alone.

Comment: you are right, am just started php. But can you tell me how to insert array data using form in php ? So i can get my mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert POST data in a table, you don't have to first fetch it from database (* this would not exist). So remove some extra code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"]);

$query = "INSERT INTO test (firstname) VALUES ('$first_name')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

And update your HTML so that the field is named `firstname` and not `firstname[]`.

**Edit:** `mysql_*` functions are not really recommended to be used anymore. But I had to answer within your question's requirements.

Comment: +1 for really answering the question as stated in the answer ("had to answer within your question's requirements").

Comment: can you tell me, array store data into a single row in database ?

Comment: for example? you mean if your table has more than one fields?

Comment: if i have 3 names along with 3 city, will they store into single row if i use array ? ie. name and city are column and have 3 row data..

Comment: You can create a table with those 3 fields. Then you can add equal number of fields to your html form. for example last_name and city. When you call "INSERT" then you can provide those values and all of them will be stored in 1 row per insert

Comment: and what if `mysql_query($query)` fails?

Comment: Then you can check with mysql_error() as to what was the reason caused the query to fail, and decide accordingly